# Blender mesh missing loop

Tags: modeling, mesh

I am newcomer to Blender and modeling in general. Currently, I am working on modeling a cat. I am noticing at times loops are missing from the polygons.

Here is an example:

[image]
[image]

Is there any easy way to fix/add a line for consistency and what is the best approach to avoid this when modeling in general for consistent topology?

Comment: Does it look the same in Edit Mode? When the edge isn't sharp enough it isn't shown in wired view. https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoPvL.gif

Comment: @palkonimo No, only shows in object mode with the mesh view. Is there anything wrong with the mesh?

Comment: When I extruded it, it now shows like you said. That side of the object was just completely flat. Thanks!

Comment: If you have a situation besides what the answer gives you, you can add a loop cut by going into edit mode and hitting Ctrl + R to add a loop cut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edge Loops are not missing, it is expected behavior, it's an optimization done by Blender for faster viewport drawing.

If an edge angle is not sharp enough to be considered an actual corner it is not drawn in object mode unless you tick the option *Draw All Edges* under the *Properties Window > Object > Display*

If you have a *Subdivision Surface* modifier on your object, the *Optimal Display* option may also cause some edges to appear to be missing.

[image: Edge Display]