# Mirror is missing edges in Edit Mode

Tags: modifiers, edit-mode, edges, mirror, object-mode

Is there a way to always make the edges show?

I enabled **Draw All Edges** located in the Object Properties panel however, in **Edit Mode** I am still not seeing certain edges due to the depth. I would like to see them on the mirror though all the time.

**Edit Mode**
[image: Edit mode]

**Object Mode**

[image: Object Mode]

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70334/blender-mesh-missing-loop/70348#70348

Comment: While this fixes the issue in Object Mode, I still have the issue in Edit Mode when wireframes are turned on. Is there any way to fix this in Edit Mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps enabling the "Adjust edit cage in modifier result" option in the Mirror modifier panel is what you need?

[image]