# Gaps in Mesh After Applying Modifiers

Tags: modifiers

I primarily use Blender for modeling 3D objects for use with a 3D printer. Most of my previous experience has been with simpler geometric models (like simple robots and the like) and I have recently started trying to make more organic objects. As part of the process I use boolean modifiers to reduce the amount of non-manifold geometry before printing. However, I've noticed that I get an issue where the meshes appear to be complete in solid view but not in wireframe view.
[image: Mesh in Solid View]

[image: Mesh in Wireframe View]

I'm not really sure where these holes come from, but they primarily seem to show up through the use of the Boolean modifier (this mesh was normal until I used the Boolean-Difference at the bottom). Once the mesh degenerates like this, I can no longer reliably combine it with other meshes. I'm hoping that this is a simple fix, but the problem is difficult to describe, so I haven't found a solution. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Blender mesh missing loop](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70334/blender-mesh-missing-loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The misleading representation of wires does not mean that your mesh has holes.

The inconsistent display of wires for faster viewport display can be "corrected" with the **Draw All Edges** option.

As you noted correctly, after the boolean modifier, the wire display is not consistent with the solid representation.
[image: wire solid]

However, adding wire display in the Object's Properties Panel, shows the same wires in solid view.
[image: another image]

To show all wires, enable **Draw All Edges**.
[image: Draw All Edges]

---

There are, however, many other tools, which are useful for cleaning objects. For example:

- the Mesh Analysis Section of the Properties Panel in the 3D View
  [image]
- the "Select Non Manifold Geometry" option in the 3D View <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>
- the **3D print toolbox** addon
  [image: 3d print toolbox]

Comment: I think that answers my question pretty well. In particular, thanks for the info about the 3D Print Toolbox. Hopefully that will help me troubleshoot printing issues in the future.